# Mutiple Case Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I am trying to get an output that when there is not a null value e.g. '1,2,and3' in the 'Private' column the 'Name' columns returns 'Name Suppressed'

I know the following query works:

```
case when AM.Private is null then Name1 else 'Name Suppressed' end as Name1, Private
from AM
```

But I now have multiple columns with names that need to be suppressed.

I have tried:

```
select case when AM.Private is null then Name1 or Name2 else 'Name Suppressed' end as Name1, Name2, Private
from AM
```

And

```
select case when AM.Private is null then Name 1 then case when AM.Private is null then Name 2 else 'Name Suppressed' end as Name1, Name2, Private
from AM
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Desired results in tabular format would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want two `case` expressions:

```
(Case when AM.Private IS NULL then Name1 Else 'Name Suppressed' END) AS Name1,
(Case when AM.Private IS NULL then Name2 Else 'Name Suppressed' END) AS Name2,
Private From AM
```

Comment: Yes, this is perfect! Thank you,